# Need to resolve AWSCore version dependency for AWSAppSync and AWSMobileClient

Tags: swift, cocoapods, aws-amplify

I want to install AWSAppSync and AWSMobileClient, both of which depend on different versions of the AWSCore. How can I resolve this conflict in the AWSCore version dependency so that I can install both AWSAppSync and AWSMobileClient

I am trying to install the following pods:
pod 'AWSAppSync', '~> 2.12.0'
pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.10.0'

However, AWSAppSync depends on AWSCore ~> 2.9.0 whereas, AWSMobileClient depends on AWSCore = 2.10.0. So based on whatever AWSCore version I install, I can install one of the two required pods. I have run the following already:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

which didn't not work. 
I have also tried removing the master repo and running

```
pod setup
```

again, but without any luck.

I essentially get the following error when I run pod install

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AWSCore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    AWSCore (= 2.9.10, ~> 2.9.0)

  In Podfile:
    AWSAppSync (~> 2.12.0) was resolved to 2.12.2, which depends on
      AWSCore (~> 2.9.0)

    AWSMobileClient (~> 2.10.0) was resolved to 2.10.0, which depends on
      AWSAuthCore (= 2.10.0) was resolved to 2.10.0, which depends on
        AWSCore (= 2.10.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by updating by updating AWSAppSync to version 2.14.0 in my Podfile. This is how my Pods look now:

```
  pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.10.0'
  pod 'AWSAppSync', '~> 2.14.0'
  pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.10.0'
  pod 'AWSAuthUI', '~> 2.10.0'
  pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn', '~> 2.10.0'
```

I found the solution documented on the
[AWS Amplify docs](https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs/pull/843)

If the issue persists after this change, depending on your system, you may need to clear your pods cache and in some cases delete your pod files, re-install them and then do a pod update.

Commands to delete, instal and update pods can be found here - https://gist.github.com/mbinna/4202236

If you are using a version management system, which I recommend, you must run these commands on the correct path

Please reach out if you have any questions about how pods work :)

Comment: Thanks. That is correct. Raised this on gitbub aws issues as well [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1833). I was told to change version to 2.14.0. That still didn't work, so was told to clear pods cache, remove pods and do ```pod update```. I did so using instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/4202236). Please update your answer to reflect this and I will go ahead and accept it.